# Can such a set of vectors exist?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Is it possible, given $n\geq 3,$ to find $\{\mathbf{x}_1,\;\mathbf{x}_2,\;\dots,\;\mathbf{x}_n\}\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ satisfying:

- $\mathbf{x}_i,\mathbf{x}_j$ linearly independent for any distinct $i,j$
- $\mathbf{x}_i,\mathbf{x}_j,\mathbf{x}_k$ linearly dependent for any distinct $i,j,k$

I can't see why this wouldn't be possible, but I am having trouble finding an explicit example. Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you looking for something like $\left\{\begin{pmatrix}1\\1 \end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}1\\0 \end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}2\\1 \end{pmatrix}\right\}$?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That $\mathbf{x}_i$ and $\mathbf{x}_j$ are linearly independent means they span a plane $P_{ij}$. That $\{\mathbf{x}_i,\mathbf{x}_j,\mathbf{x}_k\}$ is linearly dependent means that $\mathbf{x}_k \in P_{ij}$. For all distinct $i,j,k$. That means $P_{ij} = P_{km}$ for all $i\neq j$ and $k\neq m$. So it remains to find $n$ pairwise linearly independent vectors in a plane. Take for example $n$ points on the unit circle in the first quadrant.

Answer (score 2):

This is absolutely possible.

For instance, let
$$
\mathbf{x}_i=\langle1,i,0,0,\ldots,0\rangle.
$$
Then if $\alpha_i\mathbf{x}_i+\alpha_j\mathbf{x}_j=\vec{0}$, it must be the case that $\alpha_j=-\alpha_i$ to get the correct first coordinate... but this doesn't work out for the second coordinate.

Now, note that the span of any two vectors is the two-dimensional subspace $\{\langle x,y,0,0,\ldots,0\mid x,y\in\mathbb{R}\}$, which clearly contains any third vector.

Answer (score 1):

if $n=3$, we have : $x_3 = x_1 + x_2 $
It is easy to see that $(x_1,x_2)$,$(x_1,x_2)$,$(x_1,x_2)$ are linearly independent but $(x_1,x_2,x_3)$ is linearly dependent.

Comment: Note that this works iff $\mathbf{x_1,x_2}$ are given as linearly independent.

Comment: yeah, good remark ;)